# how can i operate the element of the xml use the actionscript

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, xml-parsing

```
<fpdl:StartNode Id="Goods_Deliver_Process.START_NODE" Name="START_NODE" DisplayName="">
    <fpdl:ExtendedAttributes>
        <fpdl:ExtendedAttribute Name="FIRE_FLOW.bounds.height" Value="20"/>
        <fpdl:ExtendedAttribute Name="FIRE_FLOW.bounds.width" Value="20"/>
        <fpdl:ExtendedAttribute Name="FIRE_FLOW.bounds.x" Value="11"/>
        <fpdl:ExtendedAttribute Name="FIRE_FLOW.bounds.y" Value="117"/>
    </fpdl:ExtendedAttributes>
</fpdl:StartNode>
```

fpdl is the namespace of xml, how can i operate the element of the xml by using the actionscript.I try to use example.["fpdl:ExtendedAttribute"] to visit the element, but it doesn't work.

Thanks.

Comment: Not an answer to your question but you might want to use all lowercase for your attributes, since thats the common practice(at least I think so).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a more complete manual of AS3 XML namespaces.

```
var data:XML = <fpdl:StartNode Id="Goods_Deliver_Process.START_NODE" Name="START_NODE" DisplayName="" xmlns:fpdl="http://google.com">
    <fpdl:ExtendedAttributes>
        <fpdl:ExtendedAttribute Name="FIRE_FLOW.bounds.height" Value="20"/>
        <fpdl:ExtendedAttribute Name="FIRE_FLOW.bounds.width" Value="20"/>
        <fpdl:ExtendedAttribute Name="FIRE_FLOW.bounds.x" Value="11"/>
        <fpdl:ExtendedAttribute Name="FIRE_FLOW.bounds.y" Value="117"/>
    </fpdl:ExtendedAttributes>
</fpdl:StartNode>;

// define namespace if you know its URL
var ns:Namespace = new Namespace("http://google.com");      
trace(data.ns::ExtendedAttributes.length());

// get namespace from document
ns = data.namespace("fpdl");                                
trace(data.ns::ExtendedAttributes.length());

// get default namespace from document
ns = data.namespace();                                      
trace(data.ns::ExtendedAttributes.length());

// set default namespace to use
default xml namespace = ns;
trace(data.ExtendedAttributes.ExtendedAttribute.length()); // see, no ns:: stuff
```

Personally I find *default xml namespace = ns;* to be damn ugly.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing XML with E4X in Actionscript and using namespaces is a little tricky at first. Here's a quick solution that should get you going.

http://www.cafesilencio.net/blog/accessing-xml-with-namespaces-in-as3-flex-air

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Namespace` instance and the scope resolution operator `::`. Here is an example:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {

        public function Main():void 
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

        }// end function

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

            var xml:XML = 
            <root xmlns:ns="http://www.namespace.com/ns" >
                <ns:parent value="parent">
                    <ns:child>child</ns:child>
                </ns:parent>
            </root>;

            var ns:Namespace = new Namespace("http://www.namespace.com/ns");
            trace(xml.ns::parent.@value); // output: parent
            trace(xml.ns::parent.ns::child); // output: child

        }// end function

    }// end class

}// end package
```